# Converting latlong into PostGIS geometry?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have this excel spreadsheet with latlong coordinates in it and imported it into Postgis

Problem is that I can't represent it on Geoserver because there is no typical Postgis geometry column

How to create this geometry column using the 2 coordinate fields?

Comment: Besides the valid answer given by @thibautg, another way is to use a [SQL View](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Add a new geometry column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);
```

2) Update the new column with the geometry from your `long` and `lat` columns:

```sql
UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326);
```

Comment: I assume I replace long and lat for the respective columns however I got ERROR: column "field4" does not exist. field4 is my longitude column

Comment: Yes. If your column name has capital letters, you must enclose the field name in double quotes. Ex: `"Field4"`.

Comment: I got this http://i.imgur.com/iexCq1o.png

Comment: It seems that your fields are stored in text and not in double precision. Try casting them: `UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("Field4"::double precision, "Field 3"::double precision), 4326);`

Comment: Now I got ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "longitude". Could it have something to do with the fact that my first row is the column name?

Comment: I guess that the first line in your table contains your column's names because of a bad import (you probably used QGIS which does not always recognize column names correctly with Excel files). This is the reason your fields are called "Field4" etc. Try deleting the first line of your table, where you see the column names instead of values. Or import your excel file with the correct headers.

Comment: Yes! it Worked! thanks. I did use the QGIS importer instead of the postgres one so extra props for guessing that one